# ember-cli meta config/environment file

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm using ember-cli to structure my app.

It compiles all the files to the `dist/` directory.

However as I inspected the compiled `index.html` I noticed it was creating this meta tag.

```
<meta name="user/config/environment" content="%7B%22modulePrefix%22%3A%22user%22%2C%22environment%22%3A%22development%22%2C%22baseURL%22%3A%22/%22%2C%22locationType%22%3A%22auto%22%2C%22contentSecurityPolicy%22%3A%7B%22default-src%22%3A%22%27none%27%20localhost%22%2C%22script-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%20%27unsafe-inline%27%20%27unsafe-eval%27%20use.typekit.net%20connect.facebook.net%20maps.googleapis.com%20maps.gstatic.com%22%2C%22font-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%20data%3A%20use.typekit.net%22%2C%22connect-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%20localhost%22%2C%22img-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%20www.facebook.com%20p.typekit.net%22%2C%22style-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%20%27unsafe-inline%27%20use.typekit.net%22%2C%22frame-src%22%3A%22s-static.ak.facebook.com%20static.ak.facebook.com%20www.facebook.com%22%7D%2C%22EmberENV%22%3A%7B%22FEATURES%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%22APP%22%3A%7B%22LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION%22%3Atrue%2C%22LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22exportApplicationGlobal%22%3Atrue%7D">
```

This is a problem for my deployment as I'm currently using the ember-app within another page and this meta tag is needed for the ember app to work. Is there a way to make this as part of the javascript compiled file or get rid of this altogether?

Comment: Are you setting the env to production while building? `ember build --environment=production`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The ability to build your app without this was recently added in [this PR](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/pull/2298)

You can set it up to be in your compiled JS output by passing in the `storeConfigInMeta` option. To opt-out, it should look like this in your `Brocfile.js`

```
/* global require, module */

var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

var app = new EmberApp({
  storeConfigInMeta: false
});

module.exports = app.toTree();
```

This is available in ember-cli 0.1.2 which is the latest version right now

Comment: this is now `ember-cli-build.js`

Comment: This flag is really useful to hide some sensitive information leakage from ENV object of the environment.js file.