# Remove meta tag created for ember engine in index.html

Tags: ember.js, config, meta-tags, ember-engines

I can see meta tag about the config information of the app can be removed from being stored in index.html through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26614186/4531934).

I need the same to be done for my ember-engine. Currently, this is how my index.html looks. It contains the two meta tags: one about the engine's environment.js and the other about the asset-manifest.json.

```
<meta name="inventory/config/environment" content="%7B%22modulePrefix%22%3A%22inventory%22%2C%22environment%22%3A%22development%22%7D" />
 <meta name="app/config/asset-manifest" content="%7B%22bundles%22%3A%7B%22inventory%22%3A%7B%22assets%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%7D%7D" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet here is creating an in-repo-addon because addons have access to a [postprocessTree](https://ember-cli.com/api/classes/Addon.html#method_postprocessTree) method. It's going to require getting into the Broccoli build though and messing with the `html` output and I'm not sure exactly what that will look like.

`ember g in-repo-addon remove-engine-config`

```
//lib/remove-engine-config/index.js 
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  name: require('./package').name,

  postprocessTree(type, tree) {
    //console.log(type, tree)
    if (type === 'html') { //just guessing on html, it could have a different name
      //do some broccoli manipulation to target and remove the meta tag
      return fancyBroccoli(tree);
    }
  }
};
```

I'd recommend getting familiar with VS Code and it's excelent debugger because that will let you inspect things as they come into that method, or you can just put a `console.log(type, tree)` and see what shakes out to start.

Here is a good resource for [getting started with Broccoli](http://www.oligriffiths.com/2017/01/26/Eat-your-greens-A-beginners-guide-to-Broccoli-js/)

Comment: Thanks for answering. But removing meta tag alone will not solve the problem. Ember needs the meta information about the engine. I want it to configure the same in the vendor.js or mdmp.js and lookup in those files.

Comment: Ah. I'm sorry. i completely misread your question and I don't actually have an answer for you.